# How to use whereToEqual on sub object array with unknown field

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let me show you the Firestore document structure.

[image]

How I can compare the `stops` array values? because time `12:00 PM` will be different for each entry in the departure.

So actually I want to get the value of `buss` where the my given value match to any value of the `stops` array.

Comment: Is it still helpful for you, if I will provide you the database structure that Frank van Puffelen was talking about?

Comment: @AlexMamo that will be a great support for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Frank van Puffelen's answer, because Firestore does not support querying array members, you should consider change your database structure a little bit. So instead of using arrays you should use `maps`. So inside each document you need to add a `map` that will look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- buses (collection)
        |
        --- busId (document)
              |
              --- buss: "/buss/OdGpiY..."
              |
              --- stops (map)
                    |
                    --- IQdng...526MpZ: true
                    |
                    --- pnwJ...4P3ef: true
```

As you can see, I have add a new map named `stops` inside the bus document that contains as key, the name of the station and as a value the boolean `true`. Using this database structure you can query your database based on elements that exist inside the map like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference busesRef = rootRef.collection("buses");
Query query = busesRef.whereEqualTo("stops.IQdng...526MpZ", true);
```

Comment: I'm just building the admin panel to add the data then it will be easy for me to fetch the data. Here I have asked another question related to admin panel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310280/how-to-pass-async-data-from-controller-to-view-in-nodejs-framework-adonisjs

Comment: I don't know Node.js, sorry but do you think that my answer for this question helped you?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. May be this question can help you to understand what I'm talking about? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348639/firebase-for-mvc-based-projects

Answer (score 0):

From the [Firestore documentation on arrays](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays):

> Although Cloud Firestore can store arrays, it does not support querying array members or updating single array elements.

To allow querying for routes that contain a certain stop, you should store an additional field in the document that contains the stops as a set:

```
stops
  IQdng...526MpZ: true
```

Now you can query for routes with that stop by doing:

```
routesRef.whereEqualTo("stops.IQdng...526MpZ", true)
```

You'll still need your original structure for the stops too, since that's the only way to know the order of the stops and the time of each stop.

Comment: how to access `stops`? I don't need to give the complete path? like `departure.*.stops` I used * because time will be different for each value.

Comment: If that is not possible can you suggest me the right structure for the database?

Comment: As I said: you will need to an **additional** field to each document where you keep the stops in the format I showed. Please also read the documentation I linked, which explains it in more detail.

Comment: should I remove the existing array with time?

Comment: I have already read that document, but didn't found the help which can help me to manage my data.

Comment: I have updated the image, please take a look now and let me know how I can make this structure better or compare the array value.