# Firebase for MVC based projects

Tags: node.js, spring, laravel, firebase, model-view-controller

I'm struggling with `Firebase` due to it's asynchronous behavior. Let me explain what problem I'm facing

As you know in MVC we do logic in our Controller, and then pass the output or data to the VIEW. But using `Firebase` we can't pass data to the view because Controller will not wait for `Firebase` response and will initialize the VIEW.

```
class Controller{
  index(){
    var data = getDataFromFirebase(); // controller will not wait for this
    return view('users', data);
  }
}
```

So how we can handle this situation? How to get the data from the `Firebase` and then pass to the View in Controller.

I have test it in `Laravel`, `Adonisjs -NodeJS Framework`, `Spring Boot MVC`
But not works in any framework  to check may be there could be a solution for this problem but didn't found any one. You can suggest the solution in any framework or language as I mentioned.

Comment: Did you consider using rxJava or something like that as an observable data holder?

Comment: @vanillaSugar I don't know about rxJava. But in the above framework there will no option? really?

Comment: I guess that you should get data from firebase asynchronously. This data should also be mutable asynchronously in your view. You should wrap your data to observable or something like that.

Comment: @vanillaSugar any code example?

Comment: I couldn't find code example related to your situation, but maybe this will help you understand what I mean https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#building_the_user_interface . Check out how User is wrapped in LiveData .. (LiveData<User>)